# recreate fragment android

Tags: java, android

tengo un problema al tratar de actualizar la vista de un fragment.

Tengo un fragment que muestra los datos obtenidos desde firestore, desde el abro una activity nueva para realizar algunas updates en la db ( esta se abre en modo dialog ), quiero que al cerrar la ventana ( activity ) se vuelva a recargar el fragment mostrando los datos nuevos.

Probé con OnRestart onResume pero ambos también se ejecutan cuando inicio el fragment, yo solo quiero que se recargue cuando cierre la actividad que inicie.

Comment: `private static boolean restarted = false;`, luego al reiniciar el fragmento seteas `restarted` a `true` y ya tienes un flag que te indicará si es la primera vez que se ejecuta el `onRestart` o el `onResume` o no, y puedes usarlo como condición para ejecutar lo que quieras

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es

> "solo quiero que se recargue cuando cierre la actividad que inicie."

Lo puedes realizar dentro del método  `onDestroy()` de la activity:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```